# Limiting browser connections to only 1 persistent

Tags: http, iframe

I am converting a program that used to connect via telnet into working via http. I need to limit the browser to have one and only one open connection to the server per each session ( tab ). Is that possible somehow ? As I am implementing the server directly, may I do something on that side ?
I need also that session to be persistent and the same up to when the tab is closed. Is that possible ?
( the problem is that the design of the previous application is starting a new task for every connection and the application isn't stateless ).

Answer (score 0):

Using firefox I went to "about:config" and changed the setting

```
network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server
```

setting it to 1.

As I also wanted the connection to persist indefinitelly I changed too

```
network.http.keep-alive.timeout
```

to a big number.